# Getting my output into another excel file

Tags: python

```
import os, sys
from xlrd import open_workbook
from xlutils.copy import copy
from xlwt import easyxf, Style
import time

rb =  open_workbook('A1.xls', on_demand=True,formatting_info =True)
rs =  rb.sheet_by_index(0)
wb = copy(rb)
ws =  wb.get_sheet(0)

start =time.time()
g1 = dict()

for row in range(1,rs.nrows):
    for cell in row:          
        cellContent = str(cell.value)

        if cellContent not in g1.keys():
            g1[cellContent]=1
        else:
            g1[cellContent]=g1[cellContent]+1  

for cellContent in g1.keys():
    print cellContent, g1[cellContent]
    ws.write(row,1, cellContent)

wb.save('A2.xls')
```

When I run this code, I get the error message  `cell` object not iterable
What could have gone wrong?

Comment: I've reformatted the code, but obviously as it's python indentation levels matter. Please can you confirm that the indentation is still correct. Regardless, I believe it's correct enough that your issue will be present.

Comment: The problem is with the line: " for cell in row:"  with the error message " integer object is not iterable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you've got is that `row` is an integer, as it's populated using `for row in range(1, rs.nrows):` where the `range()` function [returns an integer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) - In your case what I presume is each row number between 1 and the number of rows in your spreadsheet.

I'm not familiar with how the `xlrd`, `xlutils` and `xlwt` modules work, but I'd imagine you want to do something more like the following:

```
for row_number in range(1, rs.nrows):
    row = rs.row(row_number)
    for cell in row:
        ....
```

The [`Sheet.row(rowx)`](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html?p=4966#sheet.Sheet-class) method gives you a sequence of `Cell` objects that you can iterate in your inner loop.

Comment: When I use this code snippet: for row_number in range(1, rs.nrows):
    row = rs.get(row_number)
    for cell in row: I get another error message: "Sheet' object has no attribute "get"

Comment: @Bethogee That snippet was illustrative - I'm _not_ familiar with the actual methods available, but I was trying to highlight the problem you've got. I'll try and re-word my answer, but the problem is that `row` is the integer id of the row, not the entire row itself. I _guess_ that the libraries you're using have some way to access the _actual row_.

Comment: @Bethogee - Looking at [the docs](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html?p=4966#sheet.Sheet-class), I think you want to use the `Sheet.row()` method, as in my updated example. This gives you a sequence of `Cell`s that you can iterate through in your inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar myself with `xlrd` or any of the other modules, but  doing any work with csv or excel spreadsheets, I use Pandas, specifically this [link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html). It allows you to easily read and make all sorts of modifications, and then write it out very easily as well. If all you wanted was to copy it would be really easy.