# Installing the latest version of XLRD

Tags: python, xlrd

I am already using an `xlrd` package. The code I am working on always returns an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "diffoct8.py", line 17, in <module>
    row = rs.get(row_number)
AttributeError: 'Sheet' object has no attribute 'get'
```

What could be the problem?

Is there a newer version of XLRD?. If yes, how can I install it in Ubuntu?

Comment: You appear to have a problem on line 17, because the `Sheet` object has no attribute `get`. It's hard to say anything else without looking at the code.

Comment: Gives us the code, precious, then we helps...

Comment: The code provided is sample code I wrote to illustrate a problem in [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26259159/getting-my-output-into-another-excel-file/26259606#26259606), and I did at the time state the I didn't know if a `get()` method existed, but I suggested there would probably be something to do what was wanted. I've since edited my answer having looked at the docs for the user.

Comment: If there is a newer version, you can install it with `pip install xlrd`. I would also make a point of using Virtualenv for any Python development.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can get latest xlrd package. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd

From my understanding, you just want to get information from a row in a sheet. I assume there are 10 elements in a row.
Try this:

```
...
element_num = 10
row = []

for i in xrange(element_num):
    row.append(rs.cell(row_number, i).value)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `get()` does not exist (It was purely used to show the *approach* you should take and where the problem was in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26259159/68556)). I've update [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26259606/68556) to that question to show you how you should use the `row()` method, as instructed in [the documentation](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html?p=4966#sheet.Sheet-class).